# How to skip a before_filter in dev environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, before-filter

I want to skip before_filter `authenticate_user!` when it's in `Rails.env:dev`. Otherwise, do the authenticate action in `Rails.env:product`

Comment: Which version of Rails do you use?

Comment: @FarkhatMikhalko rails 4.2.11 on ruby 2.4.5

Comment: Sebastian's answer works well with this version.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `skip_before_filter` with the `if` option:

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, if: -> { Rails.env.development? }
```

(`skip_before_action` depending on your Rails version)